# How do I make a dictionary that stores the values I replace without importing defaultdic?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am trying to make a function that replaces the values inside my list of dictionaries to integers. The function I made works on replacing the values, but not storing the replaced values

```
sample=[{1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'C', 4: 'A', 5: 'C'}, {1: 'A', 2: 'G', 3: 'A', 
4: 'C', 5: 'A'}, {1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'T', 4: 'A', 5: 'A'}]
def updatevaluedict(dictionary,va):
'''takes in a dictionary and replaces the values that you
    want with ones'''
emptydict2=[]
for individual_dict in dictionary:
    for key in individual_dict: 
        if individual_dict[key] ==va:
            individual_dict[key]=1###LOOK HERE
        else:
            individual_dict[key]=0
return dictionary
```

This prints out the values I want

```
print(updatevaluedict(sample,'A')
```

I'm trying to replace the values that I want with '1's and the rest with '0's.
However, all the values in the actual dictionary have been replaced to 0's

Comment: I have updated my answer to allow the modification of a single dictionary from the list, and not the whole list

Answer (score 0):

This will modify the existing dictionary, not sure what you're trying to achieve so this replaces all values with the number 1

```
sample=[{1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'C', 4: 'A', 5: 'C'}, {1: 'A', 2: 'G', 3: 'A', 
4: 'C', 5: 'A'}, {1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'T', 4: 'A', 5: 'A'}]
for dct in sample:
    for k in dct:
        dct [k] = 1
print (sample)
```

prints (on one line):

```
[{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}, 
{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}, 
{1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5: 1}]
```

Alternatively to pass one of the dictionaries to the function and modify it, you would use a list index like:

```
sample[0]
```

as below (this also let's you choose which integer to replace the dictionary values with, by changing the "number" variable):

```
def replace(dct,number):
    for k in dct:
        dct [k] = number
    return dct

number = 2
sample[0] = replace(sample[0],number)
print (sample)
```

prints (on one line):

```
[{1: 2, 2: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 5: 2}, 
{1: 'A', 2: 'G', 3: 'A', 4: 'C', 5: 'A'}, 
{1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'T', 4: 'A', 5: 'A'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sample=[{1: 'A', 2: 'A', 3: 'C', 4: 'A', 5: 'C'}, {1: 'A', 2: 'G', 3: 'A', 
         4: 'C', 5: 'A'}, {1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'T', 4: 'A', 5: 'A''}]

def updatevaluedict(individual_dict, va):
    '''
    takes in a dictionary and replaces the values that you
    want with ones
    '''
    for key in individual_dict: 
        if individual_dict[key] == va:
            individual_dict[key] = 1###LOOK HERE
        else:
            individual_dict[key] = 0
     return dictionary

def update_list(ll=[]):
    # update list of dictionary
    new_ll = []
    for each_dict in ll:
        new_ll.append(updatevaluedict(each_dict, va))
    return new_ll
```

Comment: I'm trying to replace the values that I want with '1's and the rest with '0's

Answer (score 0):

By running you code I noticed that you have an extra `'` at the end of the last dictionary: `{1: 'A', 2: 'C', 3: 'T', 4: 'A', 5: 'A''}`

Other than that your code ran just fine with python 2.7.12